# Gerrit replication, reject HostKey

Tags: git, gerrit

I am trying to set up `gerrit` replication on my environment, but I am getting `reject HostKey` output.

The `pubkey` of the user running `gerrit` is in the `authorized_keys2` file on the remote host, however I am able to ssh just fine when I manually do it in the terminal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing this as the same user ? What are the permissions on the authorized_keys2 file and the .ssh directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Can we get the exact command and messages for clarity?

In `ssh`, the host keys are independent from the user ones.

`authorized_keys2` should now be renamed into `authorized_keys` as `authorized_keys2` was deprecated long ago.